# Get Value Of Table Field

Tags: php, html, html-table

I am using php to echo query results out to a table like so

```
    echo '<table border="1">';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '  <th bgcolor="#FFFFFF" >Team Name </th>';
    echo '  <th bgcolor="#FFFFFF" >Player Name </th>';
    echo '  <th bgcolor="#FFFFFF">Jersey Number </th>';
    echo '</tr>';  

while ($Row = mssql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
    echo '<tr><td>' . $Row['Team Name'] . '</td><td>' . $Row['Player Name'] . '</td><td>' . $Row['Jersey Number'] . '</td></tr>';
}
    echo '</table>';
};
```

I want `Jersey Number` to be a hyperlink which can read the value of `Player Name` and pass that to a php file to be used as a query parameter and pull data for that specific player when the page loads.

Sample data is like

```
Team Name --- Player Name --- Jersey Number
Red           Bob Jones       12
Blue          Jack Horner     14
```

So if you click on 14, the code would read Jack Horner and store it in a variable.  How is this achieved with php/html?

**EDIT**
Something like this is what I am after...using one page to redirect to and passing in the `player name` to use as a parameter.

Brief explanation, set the hyperlink to a page called other.php, and pass in the as part of the `QueryString` the value of `.$row['name']`

I tried the below syntax, but it gives me a 500 error

```
echo "<td><a href='other.php?playername=".$row['Player Name']'>" . $row['Player Name'] . "</a></td>";
```

Comment: You haven't really show us anything you've tried, just really asking us to do it for you. Try some code yourself, then come back to us if you have issues.

Comment: @MatthewBergwall - my apology, I omitted the portion of code that I tried that threw a 500 error.  Please see my edit.